# How can I fix my code to find a certain character in an array and make changes to that array

Tags: java

```java
    while (scan_file.hasNext()) {
        String b = scan_file.nextLine();

        // checks if string b contains the tag <h>
        if (b.contains("<h>")) {
            char arrayString[] = b.toCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++) {
                if (arrayString[i] == '<') {
                    arrayString[i] = arrayString[i + 2];
                }

                System.out.print(arrayString[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I was expecting the program to do was(for now) iterate through the while loop and store each line as string 'b'.
I want to check if that string b contains a certain string like  `<h>`  for this example. And I want to convert string b into an array if it contains said string like `<h>` and iterate through that array to check for '<' and move the array up 2 spaces.

For example, string b had `<h>hello`, I wanted to eventually print `hello` because the program would have moved up 2 elements.

I feel like I got the loops and general idea on how I want to tackle the problem.. but when I ran the program, nothing printed so I don't know if I did the loops and if statements correctly.

I really don't know how to word my problem well, so bear with me and I'm sorry in advance.

All feedbacks are greatly appreciated (:

Comment: `if (b.trim().contains("<h>")) { System.out.println(b.substring(b.indexOf("<h>") + 3)); }` Or you could use: `String tag = "<h>"; if (b.trim().contains(tag)) { System.out.println(b.substring(b.indexOf(tag) + tag.length())); }`

Comment: Are you using an IDE (integrated development environment, e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse)?  If you, so you should be able run your program on a debugging mode.  Put a break point at the start of the for loop, then run the program line by line to see what it's doing compared to what you think it ought to be doing.  Many a problem can be solved thus!

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print(arrayString[i]);` just print the ith character of arrayString, it's definitely not what you want.

In fact you don't have to convert a `String` to `char[]`, `String` has many utils method can help you with your goal.

I won't give you full code , but I can give you some tips.

1. You can use `String.indexof('<')` to find the index of '<'.
2. You can use  `String.subString(startIndex)` to get the subString start with the specified index.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your code `scan_file.hasNext()` and `scan_file.nextLine()` is work well. You can try code below to remove all  from current line:

```
if (b != null && b.contains("<h>")) {
    System.out.println(b.replaceAll("<h>", ""));
}
```